Charge pump with MOS-error-amplifier, please help me understand this circuit
Could you please help me understand how this circuit works?
In my RF classes I was introduced the Charge pump and at some point we were given these two following schematics:


NOTE: I have no idea where those images come from, they were given me as student's material for my classes by my professor.
Now, the first one is supposed to be the same as the second one, but on a higher-level system view.
SHORT QUESTION: I don't understand how this circuit works and how the first scheme translates into the second;
LONG QUESTION: this is what I understand of the circuit:
I don't understand how the circuit works. Let's take the second image. The sub-circuit to the far right is the charge pump. Now, let's call the "On" (at the left of the buffer in the Charge pump circuit) node "X".
As far as I understood, we use the feedback control and the replica bias in order to make sure that the "Vreplica" voltage in the "replica-bias" sub-circuit is identical to the voltage on X.
Now, why would I want that?
From what I understood, there seems to be a problem when Icp (the upper charge pump current) and Idown (the lower one) are different, so I thought "ok, maybe it works like this: if Vx rises, then the right transistor of the diff. couple in the feedback control drives more current. The couple's current is set at 2I by the multiple mirror (the couple's tail transistor is"2Wn" and there's a conversion ratio of 2, ideally). So this means that the left transistor of the couple shall drive less current.
Now, keep your eyes on the feedback control: if the right current of the couple rises, then the D-S voltage shall rise, too. This means that since the drain of the left transistor is linked to the gates of the upper transistors, the Drain voltage shall become the Gate voltage of all the P-MOSs in the upper frame of the picture.
Now: since gate voltage is increasing, the MOS which drives "Icp" (upper charge-pump current) should drive less current.
This also means, though, that on the far left (replica bias sub-circuit) the PMOS should drive less current.
This is what I do not understand: if the current decreases, the Vreplica voltage should decrease, right? Then what's the point of this thing? Shouldn't it be like to keep Vreplica= Vx?
And, btw, what happens when Vreplica=Vx? Why do we want this?
Furthermore, how do you get from the first scheme to the second one?
Thank you very much.

ZODIACK - Hi, Where did the image come from? (book?) To comply with the site rule on referencing, details of the original source of copied / adapted material must be provided by you, next to each copied / adapted item. If the original source is online & public, please [edit] the answer & add the webpage/PDF/etc. name & its link (URL) (e.g. website name + webpage title + its URL). If the source is offline (e.g. printed book / private intranet) then [edit] the answer & add full source details e.g. title, author, page, publisher, edition. (More rules in [tour] & [help].)

I am going to quote a few lines of the Design of CMOS Phase-Locked Loops by Behzad Razavi:
"Charge pumps suffer from numerous undesirable effects, contributing both ripple and noise ... The greatest challenge in charge pump design relates to the output voltage “compliance” and channel-length modulation in the current sources. These two effects trade with each other. The former signifies the output voltage range that the charge pump can support while maintaining equal up and down currents ... A number of charge pump topologies have been introduced to deal with the mismatches between the up and down currents ..."
Now, let's analyze your version. The first error amplifier simply drives X to be equal to the output voltage (loop filter voltage). This means that the left branch transistors (which are on most of the time) will "see" the same \$V_{DS}\$ as the main branch transistors. Thus, the effect of the current mismatch will be highly relaxed. Since these effects translate to ripples and spurs at the PLL output, these methods are necessary for a standard type-II PLL to relax the performance requirements.
